# Add property to all objects in array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects:

```
var array = [ {'a': '12', 'b':'10'}, {'a': '20', 'b':'22'} ];
```

How can I add a new property `c = b - a` to all objects of the array?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `forEach` function:

```js
var array = [{ 'a': '12', 'b': '10' }, { 'a': '20', 'b': '22' }];

array.forEach(e => e.c = +e.b - +e.a);
   
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: shouldn't you try ES5 way

Comment: Are lambda expressions " =>" available in ES5?

Comment: @Miguel no, it's ES6, I edited with ES5 now

Comment: @Mritunjay I think if the OP can't be bothered to _try_ to solve the problem themself they should accept the answers they get, whether ES5 or ES6.

Comment: @Andy I agree, but I would say if it's not asked I would prefer being answered in ES5 way only. There are a lot of people who will view answers and might get confused.

Comment: But then we could have worked out what version to use if some code had been presented to us. The onus is on the asker to provide the details and not the rest of us to read their minds. The OP has enough rep to know how this site works by now, and this question wasn't a good one.

Comment: I think this was a good question -- I had the same question just today (in 2021). But, I agree that the OP should have at least posted what code he/she tried.

Answer (score 86):

you can use array.map,

and you should use Number() to convert  props to numbers for adding:

```js
var array = [ {'a': '12', 'b':'10'}, {'a': '20', 'b':'22'} ];

var r = array.map( x => {
  x.c = Number(x.b) - Number(x.a);
  return x
  })

console.log(r)
```

---

And, with the support of the spread operator, a more functional approach would be:

```
array.map(x => ({
    ...x,
    c: Number(x.a) - Number(x.b)
}))
```

Comment: don't understand the DV either - both `map` and `Number` are preferred for stuff like this over `forEach` and `+` respectively.

Comment: OP wants `c = b - a`

Comment: @isvforall ok, thanks for the edit;

Comment: just to add a small detail, with the spread operator you still need to assign it to `var r`, the array `array` is not mutated.