# JavaScript:- Add months to array of object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object. Array length is 12. I need to add months to each object, whats the best way to add months

```
  array = [ {name:"aa"},{name:"bb"}, {name:"cc"}.......].
```

Result I want

```
array = [ {monthName: 'January', name:"aa"},{monthName: 'February',name:"bb"}, {monthName: 'March',name:"cc"}............].
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add property to all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677787/add-property-to-all-objects-in-array)

Comment: Do i need to write each month manually? I am sure using JS we won't need it

Answer (score 1):

Since the month names are immutable and you already know the array is exactly length 12, simply do it manually, one by one. There are fancier ways to do it but none are as easy to understand or as efficient with resources.

```
array[0].monthName = 'January';
array[1].monthName = 'February';
array[2].monthName = 'March';
...
```

Comment: No, There should be another way to do it

Comment: For sure, senior developers wont push my code if I manually write months. I need to add months from Jan to Dec

Answer (score 1):

store all the months in an array
`months = ['January', 'February', 'March'.....]`

loop through your `array` and match indexes

```
array.map((x, index) => {
  if(months[index]) {
    x.monthName = months[index];
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Any other way to do it?

Comment: I thinks its not good idea to write months, there should be some method like getFullMonth

Comment: Why? Are you worried that the names of the months will change? Or that they're going to add a new month to the calendar?

Comment: there is a way like `date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });` but you will need the date in that case; is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an array of months and without mutating the array you can create `another variable` based on your `first array` and add the month as prop:

```js
let array = [{
  name: "aa"
}, {
  name: "bb"
}, {
  name: "cc"
}];

let months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR"]
const res = array.map((el, index) => ({
  name: el.name,
  month: months[index]
}));



console.log(res)
```

Comment: @developer exactly

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to declare array which will have month as below array

```
let month = ['January',February', .... ];
```

Now you have to iterate source array i.e array and push month property for each object. Code snippets provided below.

```
array.forEach(element,index)=>{
     element['monthName'] = month[index]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an array of months yourself or get it from a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

This way you are ready to work with dates later if you need much easier. You also get localization (no easy task) and short names if you prefer (e.g. 'Jan' instead of 'January').

```js
var array  = [{name:"aa"}, {name:"bb"}, {name:"cc"}];
var months = moment.months(); // or .monthsShort();

array.forEach((e, idx) => {
   if (months[idx]) e.monthName = months[idx];
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

[Here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) is the documentation on `months()` and `monthsShort()`.